# Custom Drools+Antlr in Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, wildfly-8

We're in the process of migrating our system from JBoss 5 to Wildfly and encountered an issue where there's a part of our codebase that requires a very old Drools with a specific Antlr version.

We cannot update that chunk at the moment so we have to continue using those JARs.

We're wondering how we can use our own JARs since JBoss Wildfly comes with its own Drools and Antlr?